# How to make VirtualMachines under Ubuntu accessible to every user?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a WinXP virtual machine under Ubuntu and every user on this Ubuntu should have permission to run this VM. But every time someone runs this VM, the file permissions are set `400` and `600` (accordingly `.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` and `.VirtualBox/Machines/win/win.xml`) and ownership is set to the last user. Then i change them back to `444` and `666`, so any user could access VM, but I'm looking for permanent solution.

Background: users belong to `vboxusers` group, Ubuntu 8.04, Virtualbox 4.0.16

EDIT: based on answers so far, i must explain: we need this XP VM only about 5-10 minutes a day, so running it whole time and just connecting to it is not very good solution in our workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access mode (permissions) can be changed by file owner and by *root*, right? Thus `chown root` on the files are supposed to lock out everyone but root from mangling with access modes - unless the files are recreated every time, which needs write access to the containing directory, which is not as safe to take away but worths a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it worked. I thought, i tried it already, but seems i did not.

Comment: +1 for working solution, but methinks you might be unable to modify vms, disks etc now?

Comment: @dwurf `chmod 666` (or 664 and the right group) on the files to allow modification while locking them out from breaking mode bits

Answer (score 6):

Edit the sudoers file

```
sudo visudo
```

Add a line to sudoers like the following:

```
# Give all members of the vmwin group permission to start the vm 
# called 'win' as the user 'vmuser'
%vmwin ALL = (vmuser) /usr/bin/vboxmanage startvm win
```

Add users to the group vmwin as appropriate.

Your users can start the vm with a line like this:

```
HOME=/home/vmuser sudo -u vmuser vboxmanage startvm win
```

Comment: I like the answer, but i did not get it work. Mangled with permissions more, but still i got error:`Waiting for the VM to power on... VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'win' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 0 VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee` When i log in as `vmuser` i got VM to work, but not with `sudo` while logged in as some other user

Comment: [Googling](http://www.google.com/?q=virtualbox+0x80004005) for that error message suggests a problem accessing the VM's xml configuration file, take a look at that. I tested this solution before posting, I know it's possible to make it work!

Comment: Huh, i moved whole .VirtualBox-dir to `/home/vmuser`, i `chown -R vmuser.vmwin /home/vmuser` after that. VM-machine's directory is set to `777`, win.xml to `666`. Log in as  `vmuser` and i got VM work fine, but when try with `sudo` as you suggested, fails still with same error as above....

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't enable VNC or Terminal Services on the VM and let users connect 'remotely' to it? Your question is not clear about if you want people to use the machine in turns or just all at the same time.

Comment: You mean like running VM headless whole time? We need this XP machine for 5-10 minutes in day, so it fits better to our workflow to start it just if needed. And then it is clear: start machine, do the job, close machine. And according the question: only the one who sits behind the computer should have access to the VM, no other/remote users same time. And, yes VNC or something may be still a solution, i have no background with them, but it is worth to think about it.

Comment: By rebooting VMs all the time you might use more resources than letting them up all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [vboxweb](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/) project to get all of the VirtualBox GUI's functionality available from a web interface? For direct access to VM's you should consider VNC to the VM console or a native platform method.

Comment: More than accessing the VM, my problem concerns starting it by different users. I have no need to run it whole time.